# Java Flight Recorder - how to extract the values of a custom event field?

Tags: java, field, custom-events, openjdk-11, jfr

*Java Flight Recorder* is now a part of OpenJDK 11 and offers the usage of custom events.
After a successful recording, I want to reuse the information within the events (especially my own custom events), but somehow I am unable to read the field content of an event.
I can only see the annotations, the name and the type of the fields.

Does anybody know whether this is actually possible?

JFR has a [consumer package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/consumer/package-summary.html) which allows you to read information from the files. I already apply some of the functions.

**What I already tried**

First, I access all the fields of an event:

```
event.getFields();
```

Then I iterate over the fields and access their values in a few different ways:

```
a) eventField.getDescriptor();
b) eventField.getContentType();
```

Just looking at their names, obviously none of them would give me the content. Unfortunately I couldn't find any function that could help.

**What I also tried**

I also tried a very straight-forward idea: read the content in debug modus. I thought it would offer me some insight on how to programatically extract those information.

Unfortunately, *JFR* managed to encode their recordings in a way, that during a debug procedure, one is not able to read the information, until one programatically extracted them and has it as a local variable (example: a map).

For your information, I have been using [this](https://www.morling.dev/blog/rest-api-monitoring-with-custom-jdk-flight-recorder-events/) instruction for the custom event implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short program that illustrates how you can get the values

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  if (args.length != 1) {
    System.err.println("Must specify a recording file.");
    return;
  }

  List<RecordedEvent> events = RecordingFile.readAllEvents(Path.of(args[0]));
  for (RecordedEvent event : events) {
    EventType eventType = event.getEventType();
    String name = eventType.getName();
    Instant start = event.getStartTime();
    Instant end = event.getEndTime();
    System.out.println(name + " " + start + " - " + end);
    for (ValueDescriptor field : eventType.getFields()) {
      String fieldName = field.getName();
      Object value = event.getValue(fieldName);
      System.out.println(fieldName + " = " + value);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

If you want to find example code of all aspects of JFR, you can look in the [test folder](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/test/jdk/jdk/jfr)  in the OpenJDK project. For example, the test of a [RecordedEvent](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/test/jdk/jdk/jfr/api/consumer/TestRecordedEvent.java)

Comment: why do you work with the eventType and not with the event itself?

Comment: event.getValue(fieldName) works against the event, but I need to know the name of the fields so I use EventType and ValueDescriptor. If you already know the name of the field and the type, you can do something like event.getLong("foo").

Comment: One can extract the origin of a performance deficit, but if you do it, the result is a very detailed one - some function directly from java, like IO. Do you know how to get the origin in the software we are actually testing? For example if we have an IO operation which causes trouble, I want to get as a result the line in MY program, where this IO operation is calles.

Comment: Can't you traverse the stack trace and look for the frame where there is a method that belongs to the class or package of your program?